# Simple JSON file produces Undefined error Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a simple set of HTML and JS files that both spectacularly fail, and I can't figure out why:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

```
var data = '{"name" : "Phil Powell"}';
alert(data + ' ' + data.name + ' ' + data.type);
```

But every single time I try to open this up, I get the exact same error every single time:

```
{"name" : "Phil Powell"} undefined undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? All I want to do is parse an external JSON file, and I can't seem to do it.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: `undefined` here is not an error, it's a value.

Comment: That makes no sense

Comment: No? "_Error_" is a term used when an unhandled exception occurs (execution breaks). Reading an unset property of an object is an exception which is handled automatically, we can say that all unset object properties have `undefined` as their value.

Comment: Teemu: You are not making sense.  I cannot understand why I am producing an error when I have a simple .json file and can't even read it via Javascript via a simple file

Comment: You can't include a .json file using `script` tag. You need AJAX to read .json files. JSON is a textual data exchange format, it's not JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = '{"name" : "Phil Powell"}';
```

remove the enclosing apostrophe lie shown below

```
var data = {"name" : "Phil Powell"};
```

Comment: That also produced undefined

Answer (score 1):

You data is a string. You need to first convert data to object to access by key.

```js
var data = '{"name" : "Phil Powell","type":"something"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(data + ' ' + obj.name + ' ' + obj.type);
```

Comment: Converting data to object also fails.  It can't read it as a string nor object

Answer (score 1):

Remove object quotes like :

```js
var data = {"name" : "Phil Powell", "type" : "ABC"};
alert(data.name + ' ' + data.type);
```

Comment: When I do that, it produces undefined

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

```js
var data = {"name" : "Phil Powell", "type" : "Mars Volta"};
console.log(data['name'] + ' ' + data['type']);

var data = '{"name" : "Phil Powell", "type" : "Mars Volta"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(obj.name + ' ' + obj.type);
```

Comment: That also produced an error: "Unterminated String Constant"

Answer (score 1):

In two ways you can make it work,

**1. Removing single quotes from the string**

```
var data = '{"name" : "Phil Powell","type":"something"}';
```

instead of this use below

`var data = {"name" : "Phil Powell","type":"something"};`

`console.log(data.name, data.type);`

**2. Convert your string to JSON object using `JSON.parse()`**

```
`var data = '{"name" : "Phil Powell","type":"something"}';`

`var obj = JSON.parse(data);`

`console.log(data.name, data.type);`
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try src= data.js ??

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.js"></script>
```